# Create a scatter plot with points colored based on the different columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data below

```
df<-structure(list(x1_binary = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), x2_binary = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), y = c(2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 
5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

and I want to create a scatterplot with y values on the y-axis `x1_binary` and `x2_binary` values on the x-axis which will always be 0 or 1 and the points should be colored diiferently based on if they belong to `x1_binary` or `x2_binary`. My actual dataframe goes up to `x20_binary` but I only give 2 columns here.

```
# Create a scatterplot
ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(x1_binary), y = y, color = factor(x2_binary))) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  labs(
    x = "x1_binary",
    y = "y",
    title = "Scatterplot of y vs. x1_binary colored by x2_binary"
  )
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Your data has 10 rows. How many points will be plotted? And where does each point go on the x-axis? Is that you want a column of points all the same color for each x*_binary column?

Comment: This is typically done by reshaping your data longer so the aesthetics (e.g. color) can be mapped to a variable: `data |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-y) |> ggplot(aes(x = value, y = y, color = name)) +  [the rest of your code starting with geom_point()]`

Comment: Maybe you want a filter in there too? `df %>%tidyr::pivot_longer(-y) %>% filter(value==1) %>% ggplot() + aes(x=name, y=y, color=name) + geom_point()` Otherwise the data is just a grid.

Comment: For me, I see red and blue points along x = 0 and x = 1, with y values ranging from 2 to 8.

Comment: the x axis will have only 2 values 0 and 1 and the legend all the x binary values with different colors for each one

Comment: So `df %>%tidyr::pivot_longer(-y) %>%  ggplot() + aes(x=factor(value), y=y, color=name) + geom_point()`?

Comment: points, not pints :P

Comment: maybe I'm missing something @MrFlick but the example in OP's question works fine, and yours is functionally identical, other than the colours being different. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mark I thought the issue was he wanted the same plot for up to 20 columns. My proposal would work with more than 2 columns. But maybe I missed the point too.